# Is there only one recoverable item per planet?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Whenever I launch a probe and find something on a planet, can I be absolutely sure there isn't nothing else and am I safe to leave orbit, or is there a chance that I might miss something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a [Scanning Guide](http://www.gamesradar.com/mass-effect-3-planet-scanning-guide-war-assets-artifacts-intel-and-credits/) which shows what you can get from each solar system and planet. There does not appear to ever be a case where there's more than one collectible per planet.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that I collected nearly all items that you can find by scanning in my first plathrough, and there was never a case where a location contained more than one recoverable item.

Answer (score 1):

You could also find this out by scanning the system and monitoring your % completed statistic.

Both the scanning guide and the personal experience methods could potentially be invalidated by some future DLC and this would provide a fall back method for you.